# Run index.php rather than listing files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have recently reinstalled MacOSX, and at some point (without realizing it) I made it so that a directory without index.html would try instead to run index.php.  This has since stopped working. My localhost runs .php files fine; it just doesn't do so unless you specifically tell it to.

There are lots of htaccess guides online but I can't actually find one that tells me how to solve this problem :s

Comment: The problem's not in your .htaccess file (at least, more than likely), but in your httpd.conf (The DirectoryIndex section). However, until you're more specific you might not get a good answer. What version of apache are you running, what version of PHP, pre-packaged or self-installed? etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it's the "DirectoryIndex index.php" directive in .htaccess that will do the trick.